# ASP.NET Gridview columns resizing

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, gridview

I am looking for some solution for ASP.NET GridView that will allow to resize columns. Can anybody have expirience in it and suggest the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suggesting you use [YUI-datatable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/) or any jQuery grid plugin. rather than spending time to develop resizing feature, i use 3rd part library in my ASP.NET project.